# id of dynamically created ImageView is always -1

Tags: android

I am trying to store dynamically created `ImageView` ids in a list but following gives `-1` always.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView (this);
image.getId();
```

Comment: That's exactly as expected. `View`s don't have IDs unless you assign them one, either in your code, or in the layout XML. `-1` is `View.NO_ID`.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean I have to manage the creation of unique ids of the ImageView(s) that I create or does android API provides a work around that?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on your needs. If you're keeping references to your `View`s some other way - e.g., saving them to an array, `List`, etc. - then you don't necessarily need to assign them IDs. If you're in a situation where you'll need to use `findViewById()`, or otherwise differentiate `View`s by only their IDs, then yeah, you'll have to make sure the they're unique within the hierarchy concerned.

Comment: sorry guys, yeah I haven't read about API 17+ yet, my need is to keep an ArrayList of IDs if some dynamically created ImageView(s) and if simply keep a static int variable in the class and start assinging ids from 0, do you guys see any issue there?

Comment: The IDs could conflict with the ones generated by AAPT. In that case, it's better to use a Tag as stated in @AalapPatel answer below.

Comment: roger that! will use the Tag instead

Comment: Actually, if starting your incremental numbering from 0, there's really no practical way possible that you could generate any IDs that would "conflict" with those generated by aapt. They're just too big. However, Android Studio might complain that you're attempting to set IDs that it doesn't like. Furthermore, there's nothing that says you can't have multiple `View`s with the same ID, as long as you can keep them straight. Your app's not gonna crash from that, or anything.

Comment: I just tried it with setId starting with 0 and apparently there are no issues, but I think its just safe to use Tag rather than playing with Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is expected as you haven't set the ID. If you want to identify dynamically added view you can do it two ways by setting tag and/or by ID.

Tag.

```
image.setTag("DynamicImage");

//somewhere else in the code to find this view (use rootView if fragment else its fine with just findViewWithTag method)

ImageView image = rootView.findViewWithTag("DynamicImage");
```

ID.

```
 image.setId(CONSTANT_ID_VALUE);

 //somewhere else in the code to find this view (use rootView if fragment else its fine with just findViewWithTag method)
 ImageView image = rootView.findViewById(CONSTANT_ID_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

From API level 17 and above, you can call View.generateViewId() and set it using View.setId(int).

Answer (score 1):

id - is a unique name. Before you can get it, you must add it. Also you must know, that all id-s and resources are just constants (int) in R.class. Thus, if id is not added it is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Id is usually the assigned value in your layout. As you're creating the view programmatically, you're responsible to assign one `image.setId()`. You could generate un by using `View.generateViewId()`, like so:

```
image.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Notice though that `View.generateViewId()` exists only from API 17+ onwards.